# ES 1.7.3 Elasticsearch Java client: significant terms aggregation unknown values

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Out team currently on way of migration legacy project from Elasticsearch v1.7.3 to v7.8.0. It's in most part written in Scala, so along with this we would like to replace Java client : [Maven Repository: org.elasticsearch » elasticsearch » 1.7.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/1.7.3)

And during the work, we found peace of code we very uncertain about, something like:

```
SignificantTerms.Bucket bucket = //fethced significant terms;
bucket.getDocCount
bucket.getSupersetDf
bucket.getSubsetSize
bucket.getSupersetSize
```

so we did not find what `getSupersetDf`, `getSubsetSize` and `getSupersetSize` stands for at all. In ES 1.7.3. documentation for significant terms aggregation: [Significant Terms Aggregation | Elasticsearch Reference [1.7] | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html)

Present only `doc_count`, `bg_count` and `score` per bucket. What is those methods stands for - we can only guess. One of our suggestions that `getSupersetDf` is same value as `bg_count`, but again main problem - there is no direct mapping between values in Java client and Elastic documentation.

Could you help us, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find this in [ES source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a92a647b9f17d1bddf5c707490a19482c273eda3/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/ParsedSignificantTerms.java#L139):

```
@Override
public final XContentBuilder toXContent(XContentBuilder builder, Params params) throws IOException {
    builder.startObject();
    keyToXContent(builder);
    builder.field(CommonFields.DOC_COUNT.getPreferredName(), getDocCount());
    builder.field(InternalSignificantTerms.SCORE, getSignificanceScore());
    builder.field(InternalSignificantTerms.BG_COUNT, getSupersetDf());
    getAggregations().toXContentInternal(builder, params);
    builder.endObject();
    return builder;
}
```

You can see that indeed, `getSupersetDf` stands for `bg_count`, which is the number of documents in the background (superset) that contain the term.

And [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a92a647b9f17d1bddf5c707490a19482c273eda3/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/ParsedSignificantTerms.java#L66), suggests that `subsetSize` is `doc_count`, while `getSupersetSize` points to [this calculation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a92a647b9f17d1bddf5c707490a19482c273eda3/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/SignificanceLookup.java#L75). I think it means the total number of documents in the background (whether they contain the term or not).

So to summarize:

1. `bucket.getDocCount`: foreground count, the `doc_count` in each significant
   terms bucket.
2. `bucket.getSupersetDf`: background count, the `bg_count` in
   each significant terms bucket.
3. `bucket.getSubsetSize`: total
   foreground document count, the `doc_count` that appears in the
   response outside of the bucket list.
4. `bucket.getSupersetSize`: total
   background document count, the `bg_count` that appears in the
   response outside of the bucket list.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I meant In original question, but what about else: getSubsetSize and getSupersetSize?

Comment: Edited to include the others

Comment: @IvanKurchenko of course, also added a more convenient summary

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it. Thank you!